# How to detect current page with php?

Tags: php, html

I need to detect page to do some styling on a website, right now I'm using

```
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

but this returns something like */development/en/contact.php* 
I would like something that will only return *contact.php*
is there a method to achieve this?

Comment: see php doc link:http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

It will return only the file and strips the folders. For more information see [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Note the usage of `SCRIPT_NAME` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as `REQUEST_URI` may contain additional "crap":

```
http://example.com/dev/en/contact.php/this/is/crap
REQUEST_URI: /dev/en/contact.php/this/is/crap
SCRIPT_NAME: /dev/en/contact.php
```

Answer (score 3):

This should get you what you want:

```
basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
```

Though be careful, as it will give you the same answer for files with the same name in different locations.

Answer (score 2):

`basename(__FILE__)` is also a way.
[__FILE__ 'magic' constant](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
```